# Adding external jar dynamically and registering class as beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring, classloader

I am loading a jar dynamically in a war. The jar contains some java classes which I want to register as bean. The code looks like

Load the jar file dynamically

```
Resource jarFile = appContext.getResource("file:" +<jar_file_path>);
URL url = jarFile.getURL();
URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };             
ClassLoader classLoader = appContext.getClassLoader();
```

Load the class and register it as a bean in Spring application context

```
 Class<?> daoClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.myclass");
 Object daoObj = appContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(daoClass);
```

However this loads the dao class. Now when I load the service class which has a dependency of dao class, it fails with following exception

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myclass] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:440)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:418)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:546)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a stack trace?  Does the exception happen within Spring or does it happen at `classLoader.loadClass("com.myclass");`?  Is the exception related to com.myclass or a dependency of com.myclass?

Comment: I could get the loaded to load the bean by changing the classloader and this makes the bean to load. However now when I load the second class than the dependency fails. I have modified the code

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running in a Servlet container?  If so, you cannot load classes with a `URLClassloader` using `file:`.  The path doesn't exist, it's inside a war.

Just make sure the jar is in `WEB-INF/lib` and you'll be able to `Class.forName("com.myclass")`.